# Google Apps Script Extracing Capture Group

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

For the purpose of a minimal reproducible example, assume I have this:

```
const REGEX = new RegExp(/[0-9]{4}\s([a-z]{4})/gi);

function myFunction() {
  let text = "Here is a code: 4343 nmbv can I capture and group it?";
  let match = text.match(REGEX);
  Logger.log(match);
}


...

11:02:39 AM Info    [4343 nmbv]
```

I want to be able to "atomise" the match using capture groups. Let's say I want the number part first. When I attempt to add a named capture group it fails:

```
const REGEX = new RegExp(/(?P<number>[0-9]{4})\s([a-z]{4})/gi);

function myFunction() {
  let text = "Here is a code: 4343 nmbv can I capture and group it?";
  let match = text.match(REGEX);
  Logger.log(match);
}

...

"Attempted to execute myFunction, but could not save.
```

I know that anonymous capture groups can be referenced by order when doing a substitution. But when I attempt to reference an anonymous capture group outside of the context of a regex substitution, it predictably fails:

```
const REGEX = new RegExp(/[0-9]{4})\s([a-z]{4})/gi);

function myFunction() {
  let text = "Here is a code: 4343 nmbv can I capture and group it?";
  let match = text.match(REGEX);
  Logger.log(match);
  Logger.log("$1");
}


...

"Attempted to execute myFunction, but could not save."
```

How can I obtain capture group matches in Google Apps Script?

Comment: You can group it using your 2 capture groups. But note that you missed a `(` in the last example, and you can omit the `/g` flag if you have a single line. Else you have to loop al the matches when having the global flag. `const REGEX = new RegExp(/([0-9]{4})\s([a-z]{4})/i);`

Comment: If you want to access group 1, you can use `match[1]` See a JavaScript [demo](https://tio.run/##bY67DoJAEEX7/Yobq6XAR6DwEWOFj5bKBC3WZcU1sEtgwFf8dgRiYWEzuTNzc3KuohalLHRObj1tGmlNSQiDTbDHEkbdEKokuOd8xKOxOzu@/LdzKHkk3GefR9pZMHaujCRtDbLH@hu5gxcDUkUgdacWNtiqQkGXEJA2VnP4nu/BZKcaUhjs2plT1VaEiZEUtsqhaTVYfCmZIHlpMR1t2C@813S6QqdtUzVMbcL73/9rNDl2um/GfkWb5gM)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, named capturing group syntax in ECMAScript 2018 is not `(?P<number>[0-9]{4})`, it is `(?<number>[0-9]{4})`. You need

```js
const REGEX = /(?<number>[0-9]{4})\s([a-z]{4})/gi;
```

Then, in order to get all matches, you need `String#matchAll`, it will also keep the groups. `String#match` omits all groups.

Then, once you get a match, you need to access `match.groups.<group_name>` to get the named group value.

You can use

```js
function myFunction123() {
  let text = "Here is a code: 4343 nmbv can I capture and group it?";
  let match = text.matchAll(REGEX);
  Logger.log(Array.from(match, x => [x.groups.number, x[1], x[2]]));
}
// => 11:21:45 AM   Info    [[4343, 4343, nmbv]]
```

Note that the named capturing group also receives the numeric index. Since the `(?<number>[0-9]{4})` is the first group in the regex, it had ID 1, so `x.groups.number` value is the same as `x[1]` value.

Comment: When I use a named capture group like this in an Apps Script, I can debug with it fine in the Apps Script coding environment, but when I run the same code as a Gmail add-on, it fails with this error: "SyntaxError: Invalid quantifier ?."  Are named capture groups not supported in Apps Script add-ons? I haven't seen any documentation that states that detail.

Comment: @CarmenDiMichele I can't help you with the add-ons, maybe they are run in another environment that does not support all modern regex features. Maybe there is an option allow them.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect multiple matches in a string, it's possible to use the following:

```
let regex = /(?<number>[0-9]{4})\s([a-z]{4})/gi;
let text = "Here is a code: 4343 nmbv can I capture and group it?";

let match;
while ((match = regex.exec(text)) !== null) {
  let { number } = match.groups;
  Logger.log(`NUMBER: ${number}`);
  Logger.log(`GROUPS: ${match.groups}`);
}
```

As @Wiktor stated, named groups in Javascript regex are declared through the syntax `(?<GROUP_NAME>PATTERN)`.